# How to integrate jQuery and p5js. for ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, processing, p5.js

I am having trouble figuring out how to call p5.js functions inside of the success part of a jQuery ajax function.  This link shows ajax requests being handled by either p5.js or jQuery, but not integrating both.  Is there a way to do this?  Could someone provide a bare-bones example?  Specifically, I'd like to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url : window.location.href,
  type : "POST",
  ...
  success : function(data) {
           function draw() {
             if (mouseIsPressed) {
               fill(0);
             } else {
                 fill(data["color_value"]);
               }
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}   
              },
  error : function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                                     },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you still trying to define the `draw()` function inside your ajax success function? Don't do that.

Define your `draw()` function by itself, just like the p5.js documentation tells you to. Have it access some **state**, or in other words, some variables that tell the `draw()` function what to do.

Then in your ajax success function, simply modify the value of those variables. That will modify the behavior of `draw()`, and you can draw whatever you want based on what you get from ajax.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, I was having a prolonged brain fart.  Thanks, your suggestion worked.

Comment: @DavidJ. Happens to the best of us. Glad you got it sorted.